# Unable to share / reuse specflow steps between two projects in one solution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

How to reuse steps between two projects in specflow? Though added reference                 and assembly, the step stays purple. I have two projects(for two different        modules) in one solution 
**ProjectA**
Feature
Steps
Pages

And another project as
**ProjectB**
Feature
Steps
pages

Few steps are common for both the project, situated in ProjectB. So those common steps I am trying to access in ProjectA. I have added reference of ProjectB to ProjectA also added assembly(for ProjectA). But still I can not access the steps from ProjectB to ProjectA.The steps stay purple in the ProjectA feature files.I am wondering if anyone can guide me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the stepAssemblies in the app.config of your test project.
Have a look at the documentation here: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/ (near the end)

basically you need to add a reference to let specflow know that ProjectA is using the steps from ProjectB as a set of external steps. The config is:

```
<specFlow>
  <stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="{name-of-assembly-containing-bindings}" />
  </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```